# How to select newly inserted row inserted in WITH CTE?

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, dml

I am trying to select a newly inserted row within CTE. Let's say I have a table like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo (
    name TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

And I run the following query:

```sql
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;

BEGIN;

SELECT * FROM foo;

INSERT INTO foo(name) VALUES('bar');

SELECT * FROM foo;

COMMIT;
```

On the second select I can find the row with `'bar'`. But when I change my query to this:

```sql
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;

BEGIN;

SELECT * FROM foo;

WITH ins AS (
  INSERT INTO foo(name) VALUES('bar') RETURNING *
)
SELECT * FROM foo, ins;

COMMIT;
```

I cannot select the newly created row in `foo`. Why is that?

[Dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iTGFLdkoFA4tnNRL3BfKcP/2)

Comment: My guess would be that the last select is querying table `foo` in a state before the insert inside of the CTE was completed, as they belong to the same statement. This should work: `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;

BEGIN;
  SELECT * FROM foo;
  WITH ins AS (
    INSERT INTO foo(name) VALUES('bar') RETURNING *
  )
  SELECT * FROM ins;

  SELECT * FROM foo;
COMMIT;`

Comment: Does it answer your question? https://dbfiddle.uk/3ljuJg6z

Comment: I have just read your dbfiddle, does that mean that CTE expression would run/commit in a batch implicitly? Not the commit of a transaction but a commit of a statement?

Comment: well, my point is that CTE and SELECT are part of the same statement. So, the select in the outer query is unaware of the insert, as the statement isn't yet completed/executed. The `COMMIT` in the transaction is sort of irrelevant in this case. Even if you rollback the whole transaction,  the steps in between will be the same: https://dbfiddle.uk/G-cLK1YD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I cannot select the newly created row in foo. Why is that?

Because this is how the data modifying statements were designed in Postgres.

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)

> Therefore, when using data-modifying statements in WITH, the order in which the specified updates actually happen is unpredictable. All the statements are executed with the same snapshot (see Chapter 13), so they cannot “see” one another's effects on the target tables. This alleviates the effects of the unpredictability of the actual order of row updates, **and means that RETURNING data is the only way to communicate changes between different WITH sub-statements and the main query**

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>